# Creating a Visio Repository

Tags: uml, visio

This is my first question, so forgive me if it has been asked before.

I have a lot of diagrams that I created with Microsoft Visio 2007, and would like to share them with other developers. What would be the easiest way to do that? By sharing I mean being able to view the diagram, ideally without having Visio 2007 installed, and making change requests.

Can I do this with Sharepoint? Can I use the SVG export?

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [visio plugin for internet explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d88e4542-b174-4198-ae31-6884e9edd524&DisplayLang=en) which users can install, that's probably your best solution. To avoid users having to install it you would have to export the files in some image format. You can then dump the files in a SharePoint repository; in a shared folder on your network or upload them to a website.

Answer (score 0):

Visio has some good export options available...You can create an HTML/Javascript export, though I've traditionally just exported GIF files (which is a nice fast export if you're automating a batch export), and the text stays readable (compared to jpeg) with relatively small file sizes (compared to bmp).

Though if speed/ease of use/automate-ability is not much of an issue I like to just use PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can also export your visio model as an xmi file and open it with other (free) UML tools as ArgoUML (but first, you need to transform the xmi file, e.g. using this free service http://modeling-languages.com/content/xmi2-tool-exchanging-uml-models-among-case-tools, since the XMI standard is not as standard as it should be)

This way, others cannot only visualize the file but also modify it. Caveat: the graphical layout organization of your model will be lost, only the information about the content is stored in the file